# What's the meaning of "offer" in this definition of "present"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sense #2 of *present* from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/present_3) is defined as:

> 2 to show or **offer** something for other people to look at or consider
>   **present something (to somebody)** *The committee will present its final report to Parliament in June.*
>   **present something (for something)** *Eight options were presented for consideration.*
>   *Are you presenting a paper at the conference?*
>   *He presents a convincing case.*
>   *The banks will begin to present their arguments today.*

Does *offer* in that definition of *present* mean *sense #2* of *offer* in [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/offer):?

> 2 to make something available or to provide the opportunity for something
>   *The hotel offers excellent facilities for families.*
>   *The job didn't offer any prospects for promotion.*
>   *He did not offer any explanation for his behaviour.*

or *sense #1* of *offer*:?

> 1 to say that you are willing to do something for somebody or give something to somebody
>   **offer (something)** *Josie had offered her services as a guide.*
>   *He offered some useful advice.*
>   *I don't think they need help, but I think I should offer anyway.*
>   **offer something (to somebody) (for something)** *He offered $4000 for the car.*
>   *They are offering a reward for the return of their cat.*
>   *They decided to offer the job to Jo.*
>   **offer somebody something** *They decided to offer Jo the job.*
>   *I gratefully took the cup of coffee she offered me.*
>   *Taylor offered him 500 dollars to do the work.*
>   **offer to do something** *The kids offered to do the dishes.*
>   **+ speech** *‘I'll do it,’ she offered.*

Comment: I think the senses (#1 and #2) are overlapped. The *offer* in *to show or **offer** something for other people to look at or consider* doesn't mean "to say that you are willing to do something for somebody" or "to provide the opportunity for something". However, it can mean either "give something to somebody" or "to make something available". It has a mixed sense of (giving something to) and (making something available for) other people to look at or consider, though "giving something to" alone is close enough already.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. The fact that one particular dictionary chooses to offer/present two different numbered definitions for a word doesn't imply that word has two (and only two) separate/distinct ***meanings***. Nor does the fact that they defined *present* as *show **or** offer* imply that *show* and *offer* have significantly different meanings *in the context of that definition*. So, @Theo, instead of quoting chunks from dictionaries, why don't you find *an actual example usage* you don't understand (and tell us which two ***specific*** interpretations you're torn between).

Comment: @Fumble: I would say there _are_ actual usages here; each definition has an accompanying example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think either of those definitions of *offer* map **precisely** to that usage of *offer*, found in your first definition (of *present*). When the dictionary says:

> **present** (*v*.) offer something for other people to look at or consider

the "something" in that definition is referring something *abstract*, like an *idea*. The OALD definitions of *offer* that you copied illustrate how one can be offered amenities, job prospects, reasons, assistance, money, coffee, and help. Not a bad smattering, but it would be unreasonable to expect that *offer* can't be used in any other way, or that every instance of *offer* will map nicely to one of these examples.

---

Let's go back to one of those example usages of *present*:

> *Are you presenting a paper at the conference?*

When someone *presents* a paper at a conference, they are not showing a physical object, in the same way a jewel collector might display a precious stone at a gem show.

[image]        [image]

Rather, they are presenting the conclusions of their research – they are presenting their results and their findings. In other words, they are offering someone *an idea to consider*, not *an object to look at*.

Dictionary definitions aren't always exhaustive and exclusive. It would be very difficult for a dictionary to capture all the nuances of a versatile verb like *offer*. As mentioned before, I can "offer" you:

- a good price for my car
- a good price for your car
- an answer to your question
- a suggestion about where to go on vacation
- some advice about raising your daughter
- sympathy after a relative has passed away
- my assistance in a soup kitchen

or even something you [can't refuse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeldwfOwuL8). But none of those map very well to that initial usage, in the definition of *present*.

Because some words are so flexible, your problem is not uncommon: *"I can't seem to map any of these definitions to this particular usage."* When that happens to me, the first thing I do is [consult another dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=offer&ls=a). Because each dictionary has their own way of defining a word in an effort to capture as many nuances as is practically possible, there's a good chance a different work will offer a better definition to clear up your confusion.

In this case, it's [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/offer) to the rescue. To *present* means to *offer*, and to *offer* means:

> **offer** (*v.*) to put forward (a proposal, opinion, etc) for consideration

That is Collins' meaning No. 6, out of a dozen verbal definitions.